# Restart Laravel artisan command

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan, twitter-streaming-api, phirehose

I am making a functionality in my app that listen for tweets that contains some hashtags. I use [this](https://murze.be/2017/01/easily-work-with-the-twitter-streaming-api-in-php/) way of implementing the that functionality. I am also using a Laravel 5.4 on php 7.1.

I made a back end where users can add, to a table in database, new hashtags to be listened. So I get all hashtags from database and start to listen.

The problem that i have is that when someone add new hashtag i need to restart the listener so that new hashtag to be added. The only way to stop the listener is  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> keyboard combination. Can I do stop/restart that artisan command with some PHP/Laravel code?

Comment: I am also trying to find an answer to this. Can someone help?